# Can I use inheritance for this situation, and if so, which strategy is best? (TPH vs TPT vs TPC)

Tags: inheritance, frameworks, entity

I'm relatively new to Entity Framework, and for the most part, it's going well, but now I'm at a point where I'm trying to figure out if I have to use inheritance here, and if so, which strategy to use.  After a couple hours of research, I feel like inheritance isn't what I need, but I'm really not sure, as I'm still learning. The different database structures for each type can be a bit confusing for me here.  I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Here's my example:

I have a class that I call BasePokemon.  Its basically a table with each Pokemon Species (lets say the original 150), and holds all of their common info.  Here's a simplified version below:

```
public int BasePokemonId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int PokedexNumber { get; set; }
public int BaseHP { get; set; }
public int BaseATK{ get; set; }
public int BaseDEF{ get; set; }
public int BaseSPD{ get; set; }
public int BaseSPD{ get; set; }
public string MainImageURL { get; set; }

...etc...
```

Next, I have a class called GamePokemon, which are actual instances of a BasePokemon.  Lots of their data will come from the BasePokemon table upon creation, but there are lots of other fields as well that are specific to this instance of a pokemon.  Example:

```
public int GamePokemonId {get; set; }
public int SpeciesId {get; set}
public BasePokemon Species {get; set}
public int Level {get; set; }
public string Gender { get; set; } //M or F
public int MaxHP { get; set; }
public int CurrHP { get; set; }
public int ExperiencePts { get; set; }
public int StatHP { get; set; }
public int StatATK { get; set; }
public int StatSATK { get; set; }
public int StatDEF { get; set; }
public int StatSDEF { get; set; }
public int StatSPD { get; set; }
...etc...
```

So although it gets its Name, Base Stats, Image, and other general fields from the BasePokemon, it also has tons of other fields that pertain to this specific pokemon like its current HP, its Level, Stats, etc.

So here's my question: Am I supposed to use inheritance here? Because the more research I did, the more I realized I don't think I can?

I'm currently thinking of creating the BasePokemon fields in the GamePokemon table, and when a GamePokemon is created, it will fetch all of the base info from the BasePokemon table (using the chosen pokemon species).  The reason I'm hesitant is because I'd be creating a large amount of fields in both the BasePokemon and GamePokemon tables. Is that an issue?

Thanks in advance.